# how do i upload file to azure blob from react web app?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to upload a file to Azure block blob directly from react web app(Azure) without using any middleware API.Is there any way or method?

Comment: How about the Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library: https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html

Comment: @CSharpRocks I'm getting an error like Uncaught TypeError: fs.stat is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an official docs but written in TS, i believe you shouldn't have a problem with the implementation. [Official docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/browser-file-upload-azure-storage-blob)